# Get the commit message of the latest commit of the branch that is involved into a opened pull request

Tags: git, github-actions, pull-request

Assume:

The latest commit's commit message of the branch `feature/xyz` is `add feature xyz` with SHA number `1234`. The newest commit's SHA number of the main branch is `3456`.

When I push the branch `feature/xyz` to the repo and open a pull request from `feature/xyz` to `main` a workflow pipeline will be triggered, how can I get the commit message `add feature xyz`?

note: the pull request is open and not merged

```
name: Dev deploy

on:
    
  pull_request:
      types: [opened, reopened, edited, synchronize]

jobs:
  deploy-to-dev:
      name: deploy to dev
      runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
      steps:

        - name: checkout repo
          uses: actions/checkout@v3

        - name: Set env var
          run: |
            echo commit=$(git log --format=%B -n 1) >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

`git log --format=%B -n 1` would give me something like `Merge 1234 into 3456`.

How can I get the commit message of the last commit from the branch `feature/xyz`, aka, `add feature xyz` in this case?

Comment: Before or after it has been merged to master? Does the pipeline run on a temporary merge of the would-be result?

Comment: @knittl the pull request is open, before merge to master

Comment: Yes, but from your output it looks like it is running on a temporary merge? The second head of the head would be `HEAD^2` then.

Comment: @knittl I really don't know how I made a temporary merge in github :( , I just clicked the pull request button and keep push for new commit after a peer review

Comment: In any case, `HEAD^2` should be the second parent of this merge commit. First parent very likely being the target branch, second parent being your PR branch.

Comment: Note that this is specifically described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) under the `pull_request` action: the `GITHUB_SHA` field is set to the "Last merge commit on the `GITHUB_REF` branch" (which in turn is specified as `refs/pull/<pr-number>/merge`). So [hlovdal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74118184/1256452) is correct. (I also agree that depending on the commit message in the `HEAD^2` commit is unwise.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is a really bad idea to depend on the last commit on a feature branch to be special and contain some extra valuable commit message, so I would stongly recommend against doing this. But the below is an answer to what was asked.

---

Assuming the following: The `main` branch contains commits "m1".."m5". The `feature/xyz` branch contains commits "f1".."f2", starting from "m2", e.g.

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline
* 4d5b4ee (feature/xyz) f2
* 62f9a15 f1
| * 6cf050a (HEAD -> main) m5
| * f9bd7c6 m4
| * b7860f8 m3
|/  
* 39fee03 m2
* 1c1d702 m1
* e167ed6 .gitignore
$
```

then running

```bash
$ git checkout main
$ git merge feature/xyz
```

would create a merge commit, e.g.

```
$ git log --graph --all --oneline
*   7a8474a (HEAD -> main) Merge branch 'feature/xyz'
|\  
| * 4d5b4ee (feature/xyz) f2
| * 62f9a15 f1
* | 6cf050a m5
...
```

A merge commit is a commit with two (or more) parents. You probably know that you can use `^` as a postfix to a branch/commit/ref to indicate its parent, but what when there are multiple? Just a single `^` is the same as the first parent which can be explicitly specified as `^1` and correspondingly `^2` refers to the second parent.

```bash
$ git rev-parse HEAD^
6cf050af75c8c71d441364906673690bb7f0b63d
$ git rev-parse HEAD^1
6cf050af75c8c71d441364906673690bb7f0b63d
$ git rev-parse HEAD^2
4d5b4ee433a8232300de0b62c97f613d2d812f6b
$
```

So what you are asking for sounds like the commit message for the second parent to the merge commit which you can get by running

```bash
git show -s --format=format:%s%n%n%b HEAD^2
```

when the current commit is the merge commit.